# Making sure JPA commits my transaction before another service accesses the data

Tags: jpa, jsf-2, transactions, jta

It feels so simple:

I have a `ViewScoped` bean (JPA2 + EE6 + Seam3, if that matters) where the user of the web application can invoke a method like this:

```
public void save() {
    doEntityManagerStuff(); // manipulates data in the database
    callRemoteWebservice(); // which is to read said data and propagate it to other systems
}
```

Unfortunately, `save()` starts a transaction at the opening curly bracket and *doesn't commit it before the closing bracket*, meaning that the new data is not available to the remote web service to read.

I have tried to explicitly extract and annotate the database work:

```
@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
private void doEntityManagerStuff() {
    blabla(); // database stuff
}
```

But that didn't have any impact at all. (Maybe because that's EJB stuff and I'm running on seam...?)

The only thing that worked for me so far was to inject `@UserTransaction` and force commit the transaction at the end of either `save()` or `doEntityManagerStuff()` but that felt incredibly dirty and dangerous.

The other alternative would be to turn off container-managed transactions for the entire project, but that means I'd have to make *all* my beans manage their transactions manually, *just* so I can make this one case work.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Wait, your JSF managed bean is transactional..? This is not the default behavior. What annotations do you all have on your JSF backing bean class? You should basically separate transactional methods into a true service class and then in turn inject that in your JSF managed bean.

Comment: Only ``javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped``.

Comment: @BalusC - Apparently, *everything* my web app does opens a transaction. I turned on trace logging for ``com.arjuna.ats.jta`` and I get transactions for things like requesting a static PNG from the server or even only running a ``@Schedule(...)`` method in a bean that touches neither the EntityManager nor the database at all. Something is misconfigured, that much appears to be clear. Where do I even start looking?

Comment: _"Where do I even start looking?"_ servletfilters in your web.xml?

Comment: @Kukeltje - Thanks, that's also what I thought, and indeed there are two or three. But none of them have any transactional content or annotations. **I found the culprit, though.** Our project is a weird bastard that uses EE6 with Seam in order to get ``@ViewScoped`` beans. As part of Seam comes the dependency ``seam-transaction`` in ``org.jboss.seam.transaction``. Once that is in, every call triggers ``BaseTransaction.begin``. I'll see whether I can get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I only went half-way, and that's why it didn't work. I didn't know enough about EJBs and their boudaries, and naively though just annotating the `doEntityManagerStuff(...)` method with a transaction attribute in my view-scoped CDI/Seam bean would be enough.

It isn't.

When I **moved said method into a separate, stateless EJB**, injected that into my CDI/Seam bean and called it from there, everything worked as expected.

---

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class MyPersister {
    ...

    public void doEntityManagerStuff() {
        blabla(); // database stuff
    }

    ...
}
```

and

```
@ViewScoped
public class MyWebsiteBean {
    ...
    @Inject MyPersister persister;
    ...

    public void save() {
        persister.doEntityManagerStuff(); //uses its own transaction
        callRemoteWebService();
    }

    ...
}
```