# Why does my Jboss server begin transactions for everything and anything?

Tags: transactions, jboss7.x, jta

I was wrestling with the problem of [making sure a transaction is committed before other commands are executed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405281/making-sure-jpa-commits-my-transaction-before-another-service-accesses-the-data)

I didn't get an answer, but BalusC expressed his incredulity that my... *"JSF managed bean is transactional..? This is not the default behavior. What annotations do you all have on your JSF backing bean class? You should basically separate transactional methods into a true service class and then in turn inject that in your JSF managed bean."*

I like that idea, but the thing is I don't have any transaction-related annotations on any of my beans. I turned on trace logging for `com.arjuna.ats.jta` and found that the container opens and closes transactions. So far, so expected.

But it does that for *everything.* Request a static PNG from the server? Begins a transaction. Run a method via `@Schedule`? Begins a transaction. No entity managers, databases or anything transactional involved.

**Is this the expected behavior?**

I have even deployed a new test project on the server that doesn't have database stuff, and even there Arjuna begins transactions for every call.

How am I supposed to separate my db methods into a true service bean when any and all beans I create already have active transactions attached to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Is this the expected behavior?**

Well, no. At least not as far as Java EE, JSF and EJBs are concerned. So there's that.

But the project (and enough of the pom file of the new test project I used to try and triangulate the problem) is a bastard of EE6 and Seam 3. And **[Seam 3 comes with a built-in, automatic transaction wrapper:](https://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/3.1.0.Final/reference/en-US/html_single/#transaction.requestListener)**

> Seam Transaction has a built in ServletRequestListener which automatically begins and commits (or rolls back if the transaction is set to rollback) a transaction for each request! This should end having to manually specify transactions, or wonder if a transaction is inplace.
>
> Tip
>
> Should the need arise for disabling this listener, a context param in web.xml named org.jboss.seam.transaction.disableListener set to true will disable the listener.

So, as I see it, in order to refactor my database calls into a true service bean, I have three options:

- Disable the listener
- Remove Seam Transactions from the pom entirely (`org.jboss.seam.transaction`)
- Upgrade to EE7 /JSF 2.2 and get rid of Seam

**Edit:**

That was not the entire thing, though. The `@Schedule` method was in a class annotated with `@Singleton`, making it an EJB, and those *also* are transactional by default. Annotating that particular class with `@TransactionAttribute{SUPPORTS}` (i.e. "use a transaction if there is one but don't open a new one if there isn't") took care of that.